# Where can I find patterns like "noun verb noun" etc for each type of grammatical structure so that I can categorize my sentences?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Im working on a chat bot in python using `nltk` library. I want to use the `POS` tagger to classify my sentences into categories. For start I want to divide them into four categories `"IMPERATIVE", "INTERROGATIVE", "EXCLAMATORY", "DECLARATIVE"`. Eventually I'd like to add categories like `QUESTION`, `SALUTATION` and `APOLOGY`. I'm looking for some reference on how english sentence patterns are defined. Something like a BNF for english sentences. Where can I find something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your task description doesn't sound like [POS tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging) but rather dialogue modelling: Essentially, you need to find a corpus of English sentences annotated according to their [dialogue act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_act) type. One good annotation scheme I've worked with before is [Allen and Core's Dialog Act Markup in Several Layers (DAMSL)](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/research/speech/damsl/RevisedManual/). You can also see [their 1997 paper](http://people.ict.usc.edu/~core/papers/97.Core-Allen.AAAI.pdf) for more info on how this can be used, but unfortunately I don't know of any freely-available general-purpose corpora annotated with this data.